# My Service planned via AlarmManager never starts

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

I have a NotifyService that I declared in my AndroidManifest inside the application tag :

```
        <service android:name="com.ssaurel.myapp.services.NotifyService"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="false"/>
```

I use AlarmManager to plan execution of my service :

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, NotifyService.class);
        intent.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(MyActivity.this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, date.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

My Service has the following code :

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

public class ServiceBinder extends Binder {
    NotifyService getService() {
        return NotifyService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}
private final IBinder mBinder = new ServiceBinder();


public static final String INTENT_NOTIFY = "com.ssaurel.myapp.INTENT_NOTIFY";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.i("NotifyService", "onCreate()");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);

    if(intent.getBooleanExtra(INTENT_NOTIFY, false))
        showNotification();

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

//... 
}
```

My problem is that AlarmManager never starts my NotifyService. To be sure, I use the following adb command to check if my service was correctly planned :

```
adb shell dumpsys alarm > dump.txt
```

Result contains the following about my service :

> RTC_WAKEUP #12: Alarm{39dc5d5 type 0 when 1459752420000 com.ssaurel.myapp}
>       tag=*walarm*:com.ssaurel.myapp/.services.NotifyService
>       type=0 whenElapsed=+1d0h2m7s689ms when=2016-04-04 08:47:00
>       window=-1 repeatInterval=86400000 count=0
>       operation=PendingIntent{343251ea: PendingIntentRecord{135e5cdb com.ssaurel.myapp startService}}

It seems right but it's never called. Someone would have some ideas to help me ?

Note that use an intent to start directly the Notify Service works :

```
            Intent t = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, NotifyService.class);
            t.putExtra(NotifyService.INTENT_NOTIFY, true);
            startService(t);
```

Thanks.

Sylvain

Comment: Most probably your service not getting triggered,You can try to define intent filter for you service ,it may work.

Comment: I don't understand the difference if I add an intent filter on the service. Can you explain me more ?

Comment: Implicit Intents only specify “what” they should match, using actions, categories, data, MIME types, and so on. The exact components that they will find are only determined at run-time, by the Package Manager matching it against the current applications.

Explicit Intents specify a single explicit “who” they should match, through a ComponentName. Regardless of whatever else is in the Intent, it is only associated with the exact manifest package name and class name as given in its ComponentName.